# Drupal forum post not showing on forum index

Tags: community-official-site

I posted a new topic in the Drupal "Post installation" forum. When I clicked "Save", I got a new page with my post at the URL

https://www.drupal.org/node/2465665

The post is in a red box on that page. When I go back to the forum index, the post is not listed there. It's also not listed when I go to my profile and click on "Your posts".

I don't see any message that the post is awaiting approval nor anything in my dashboard saying that my account needs anything.

What's going on? I'm not likely to get a response if people can't see my post!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red box means the post has been unpublished.  You are still able to see the post, but everyone who is not a webmaster gets a 403.

Drupal.org uses a number of automated tools to detect and unpublish unwanted posts (e.g. suspected spam).  The most likely explanation is that your post tripped up one of these automated tools.

If you believe your post was unpublished in error, request it to be republished in the Drupal.org [webmasters issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters).